# How to serialize a class with a list of custom objects?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have two classes:

```
namespace Something
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Spec
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlArray]
        public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Value
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public short StartPosition { get; set; }

        public short EndPosition { get; set; }

        public Value(string name, short startPosition, short endPosition)
        {
            Name = name;
            StartPosition = startPosition;
            EndPosition = endPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to serialize

```
var spec = new Spec();
spec.Name = "test";
spec.Values = new List<Value> { new Value("testing", 0, 2) };

var xmls = new XmlSerializer(spec.GetType());    
xmls.Serialize(Console.Out, spec);
```

I get an error:

> **InvalidOperationException**
>
> There was an error reflecting type 'Something.Spec'

Using a list of `string` I don't have any problems. Am I missing some attribute?

Comment: Try looking at that exception you get, notice that it says "see inner exception for more details", and the inner exception says: "...Value cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Value` class needs to have a default constructor if you want it to be serializable. Example:

```
public class Value
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short StartPosition { get; set; }
    public short EndPosition { get; set; }
}
```

Also not that you don't need the `[Serializable]` attribute for XML serialization and it is completely ignored by the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class.

Comment: In fact, the InnerException of the exception he got mentions this particular fact, no parameterless constructor.

Comment: @Lasse I completely forgot to check the inner exception, thanks. I was testing here, the default constructor needs to exist but it is not used for anything. So I made it thrown an exception, I need the values to be setted, a "default value" is invalid.

Comment: thanks for your clear answer and for telling me about the `Serializable` attribute that is not needed by XML serialization. I actually didn't know that. :P

Comment: @Bruno: The parameterless constructor will be used on deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your `Value` type doesn't have a constructor that can be used to create an instance when deserialising?